# no method error when saving to database fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm having people submit a question using a form, then I display all the questions on the same page. It works fine when the validation passes (minimum 25 characters) but when it doesn't pass, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Questions#create
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb where line #20 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #20):

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <% @questions.each do |question| %> <--- this is line 20
        <p> <%= question.content %></p>
        <% end %>
        </div>
```

I don't really know what's going on. Any ideas?

app/controllers/static_pages_controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @questions= Question.all
  end

  def help
  end
end
```

views/static_pages/home

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <% @questions.each do |question| %>
        <p> <%= question.content %></p>
        <% end %>
        </div>

</div>
```

app/controllers/questions_controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
#before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create]

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params) #this might not work
    if @question.save
    flash[:success] = "Question added"
    redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Add question failed. Try making the question longer."
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end

  end


  private

  def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:content)
  end

end
```

models/question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 25}
end
```

Comment: Does your questions table has any records in it?

Answer (score 0):

> It works fine when the validation passes (minimum 25 characters) but
>   when it doesn't pass, I get this error undefined method `each' for
>   nil:NilClass

It's because *Rails* unable to find `@questions` when the *validation fails*, since you didn't set it in that case. Adding it should get you going.

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)
  if @question.save
    flash[:success] = "Question added"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Add question failed. Try making the question longer."
    @questions = Question.all #All you need is to add this line
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

Comment: @nachime The key lies here `render 'static_pages/home'`. `render` just loads the page. It doesn't go to the action, so `@questions`in `home` method treated as nil.